# Running out of 1%?

Tags: translation

In a book it says:

> Not much planning, analysis, or consultation is required to pick up a
>   box of cornflakes on the way home from work. And we were running out
>   of 1% milk anyway.

I would get this, if it would be:

> Not much planning, analysis, or consultation is required to pick up a
>   box of cornflakes on the way home from work. And we were running out
>   of milk anyway.

So then it means that we bought the cornflakes (we did not forget to do it), but ironically we forget the milk (we are out of milk at home, we should have bought it too).

But what does this 1% mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, *running out of* means the same as *getting short of, running low on*.

1% milk refers to its fat content. In the UK, skimmed milk is 0.1% and standard semi-skimmed milk around 1.7%.

[image: 1% milk]

Sainsbury's milk via the [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1210239/Sales-cent-fat-milk-soar-parents-watchdogs-advice-heart.html)

Answer (score 2):

'1% milk' is the type of milk.

It's an American term for milk with a fat content of about 1% - in between what we in the UK call 'semi-skimmed' and what we call 'skimmed'.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_content_of_milk#United_States